# spring boot and react login with facebook

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have spring rest api and react frontned application. I want to facilitate user to authenticate with facebook. After successful authentication i use facebookId to check if that user is in my database, if he isn't i create a user and save him. It's the only way to create accounts in my application. I used [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) tutorial to create authentication, and it's works fine...

But two days ago i decided that i want to connect my backend with frontend and I am unable to send request to protected endpoint. When i do it, my request is redirected to /connect/facebook(with OPTIONS request method - have no idea why) and nothing happen.

I read about that i should generate tokens, but I have no idea how to associate it with facebook, and I don't even know if it is a good approach.

edit.

```
@Order(200)
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;
    private final AuthSuccessHandler customAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login/facebook"))
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<OAuth2ClientContextFilter> oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
        var registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<OAuth2ClientContextFilter>();
        registration.setFilter(filter);
        registration.setOrder(-100);
        return registration;
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter() {
        var filter = new CompositeFilter();
        List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        filters.add(ssoFilter(facebook()));
        filter.setFilters(filters);
        return filter;
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client) {
        var filter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter("/login/facebook");
        var template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
        filter.setRestTemplate(template);
        var tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(), client.getClient().getClientId());
        tokenServices.setRestTemplate(template);
        filter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);

        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler);
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("facebook")
    public ClientResources facebook() {
        return new ClientResources();
    }
}
```

Comment: If your requests are being redirected is because you have spring security configured to do so. Please share your spring security configuration so it is easier for others to help you. You can also search for "spring jwt authentication" to find information about the subject.

Comment: Yeah, I know my request is redirected, because there is no authentication. It's my first time when I try connect frontend and backend and i have no idea how to deal with this security things.